# HDMI to USB converter. Connect HDMI laptop output to USB (type C) input portable monitor

Tags: laptop, hdmi, usb-c

I have a portable monitor (Lenovo ThinkVision M14) which only accept USB Type C as input. My laptop is Asus Zenbook 14 and does not any USB which support display. The laptop have one HDMI output. Is there any chance I can connect the monitor to my laptop for extending screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Display connections over USB-C usually involve DisplayPort. HDMI is specified but I’ve never seen it.

Comment: The USB-C port is usually on the PC side, therefore direct converters usually convert into the opposite direction. Theoretically it should be possible to first convert HDMI to DisplayPort and then get the DisplayPort signal into an USB-C cable.

Comment: From the Lenovo Website: "Be sure your laptop, tablet, or smartphone has a full-function USB-C connector that supports Display Port 1.2 Alt Mode and PD2.0." No chance.